# Calendar Application

Tags: windows-7, calendar, project-management

I know Google can do this to an extent, but are there any applications that work as a calendar that I can use to sync between phones and computers?

The main purpose of this is so that employees can see times free and schedule in appointments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running windows, Outlook/Exchange would be the obvious (expensive) answer.

Google Apps would be the cheaper alternative.

You could also take a look at Zoho Calendar - there's even an outlook plug-in.

All three would allow for syncing to mobile but there will be some set-up

Comment: Zoho Calendar looks nice. Will need to play around with it some see how it works

Comment: I'll vouch for Google Apps. Depending on the size of your organization, it's not incredibly expensive and they offer extensive features.
http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/#utm_medium=et&utm_source=catch_all